# Run Karate-Gatling Performance test with Blazmeter or Taurus tool

Tags: karate

As far as I know, we can integrate Gatling with Blazemeter using Taurus yml file but when I tried to run gatling test simulation file using Taurus I'm getting this error:

object intuit is not a member of package com import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef.karateFeature.

So is there any way how to run Karate Gatling Performance Test using Taurus?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the response. By the way, Karate is an excellent tool.